# Find first null value of an Array[Int]

Tags: scala, testing, null

I'm using scala but how test if a value is null or not ? Especially in a Array[Int]

In java it's :

```
if( tab[i] == null )
```

On scala, same test , ide says :

```
comparing values of types Int and Null using `==' will always yield false
```

Thanks you

Comment: An `Int` can't be null. A Java `int` can't be null either.

Comment: For exemple, in a Array sized 15, only 11 first element are initialized with value. How can i test the 12th value. I want to find the first null value of a Array[Int]

Comment: If you don't initialize the `Int`, it will be initialized to `0`.

Comment: `Array[Int]` is primitive int, though usually `C[A]` where A is Int will incur boxing to Integer. Default for primitive int is 0.

Comment: ah thanks you, sorry for that stupid question

Comment: If you really need boxed nullable integers (probably for java interop) you can create them like this: 'val tab = new Array[java.lang.Integer](5)'

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [`scala.Null`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Null):

> Null is not a subtype of value types

If you open up a Scala session and create an `Array[Int]` of 5 elements, you can see they are all initialised to the default value, `0`:

```scala
val a: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](5)             
//> a  : Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

So to find your first uninitialised element, assuming that `0` is not a valid value for your array, then you just need to do `a indexOf 0`, and to test an individual element, just test the predicate `a(i) == 0`, for example:

```
val a: Array[Int] = new Array[Int](5)             
  //> a  : Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
//  set some dummy elements for the first few entries
for (i <- 0 to 3) a(i) = (i+ 1)
// find the entry
a indexOf 0                                       
  //> res0: Int = 4
a map (_ == 0)                                    
  //> res1: Array[Boolean] = Array(false, false, false, false, true)
```